# Strange automatic HTTP redirect (302 code)

Tags: http, http-get, http-status-code-302

While working on a web crawler, I came across this strange occurrence involving the following web page: http://abudhabitourism.ae/en/

When using wget to download this page, a status code 200 is returned and all is well.

However, when my crawler program requests this page (GET request), the server seems to return status code 302 with a strange-looking "moved-to" field in the location header:

http://sso.adta.ae/opensso/TacCDSSO?localServlet=http%3a%2f%2fabudhabitourism.ae%2f%2fcdsso.ashx&paramName=result&gotoURL=http%3a%2f%2fabudhabitourism.ae%2fen%2fdefault.aspx

Is this actually a url or a script? Any ideas on how I can handle this case in my crawler program  (i.e. to be able to automatically extract the correct moved-to url from the location header)

Thanks,
Prof. Chiraz BenAbdelkader

Answer (score 0):

I think wget follows the redirect from the 302. When I use curl to get the page, it returns the headers with 302 and the URL to follow up on.

```
curl -iI http://abudhabitourism.ae/en/
```

Comment: sure that must be what wget is doing; however my main issue is with the strange-looking move-to url; do you get the same thing with curl?

Comment: i should add that i currently don't have access to a Linux machine.

Comment: iMac-van-Stephan:~ stephan$ curl -iI http://abudhabitourism.ae/en/
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 298
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://sso.adta.ae/opensso/TacCDSSO?localServlet=http%3a%2f%2fabudhabitourism.ae%2f%2fcdsso.ashx&paramName=result&gotoURL=http%3a%2f%2fabudhabitourism.ae%2fen%2fdefault.aspx
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=muilyp55knx54k45ypy5iq55; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 05 Mar 2012 16:20:10 GMT

Comment: @iMac-van-Stephan, thanks, this is exactly what I was getting; but again notice the value in the "Location" field and that was really my question, because this value just looked strange.